# How to fill a Select with data from SQL Server? Using ASP Classic

Tags: html, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm a newbie programming on ASP Classic and I'm trying to fill a Select with information from SQL Server tables, but I got trouble trying to separate two columns, I need put a column on Value side and the other one outside option just for display the name of the option.

I'm trying to get this:

```
<option value="Field_1">Field_2</option>
```

I'm trying with different loop ways, but I still am getting 2 columns combined inside my value.

Like this:

```
<option value="Field_1Field_2"> </option>
```

This is my code - I appreciate any ideas.

Thanks

```
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQL = "SELECT id_geren, Acron FROM tbl_geren"
rs.open SQL, conect
<html>
<body>
<select id="" style="width:65px"> 

<% do until rs.EOF %>
<option value=
<% for each x in rs.fields %>
<% Response.Write(x) %>
<% next
rs.MoveNext %>
></option>
<%  loop
rs.close

%>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output like this:

```
<option value="id_geren">Acron</option>
```

but the actual output is:

```
<option value="id_gerenAcron"></option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the individual fields as they can be accessed independently;

```
<% do until rs.EOF %>
<option value=“<%= rs(“id_geren”) %>”><%= rs(“Acron”) %>”></option>
<% rs.MoveNext %>
<% loop
rs.close
%>
```